# Do you use guillemets when writing inner monologue? (Character's personal thoughts)

Tags: guillemets

Bonjour! Just a minor warning, my native language isn't French.

I was wondering if you have to use quotation marks when writing about a character's personal thoughts.

**For example:**
Cette forêt est dangereuse, pensa Elio en courant pour rejoindre ses sœurs.

Is that written correctly? Because in English we can simply use a comma to separate the inner monologue from the sentence.

Comment: In English it would depend whether you wrote the monologue in direct or indirect speech. Consider 'He thought he was sad' vs 'He thought "I am sad"'. I suspect it depends on the same thing in French too (though my French is rusty).

Comment: In English, you needn't use a comma to indicate inner monologue. This forest is dangerous Elio thought as he raced to join his sisters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is not something that has been said but just a thought not expressed verbally, a simple comma is perfectly suitable here in French. Otherwise, that might be:

> « Cette forêt est dangereuse ! », cria Elio en courant pour rejoindre ses sœurs.

Note: Not sure about English but in In French, that wouldn't qualify to be called a *dialogue* because a *dialogue* implies that more than one person is involved.

Comment: That is not an inner monologue, which is what the question asked about.

Comment: @Lambie Precisely, my answer addresses the inner monologue topic in its first sentence (*a simple comma is perfectly suitable here in French*). The remaining part of my answer addresses this part of the question "*I was wondering if you have to use quotation marks*" by explaining in what case they are used. Don't worry, I'm sure the OP got it.